# powershell script to find error from logs and restart the batch file

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-server

I am new to powershell like in nursery .I want to do automation task like whenever there is particular error occurs while processing the processing of file stops so I want powershell script to restart that file processing by trigger that particular batch file and  want to apply this script for all the clients on the same server .
while($true)
{
if(Get-Content = Get-ChildItem -path "D:\XSP\ImportHelpers"    -Tail 5 | Select-String -Pattern "TRANSPORT-LEVEL-ERROR")
{
Write-Host "Error -found - restarting service..."
Restart-Service -Name myservice -Force
}
Start-Sleep 5
}

Comment: [What is the question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.